AttributeError: 'DynamoHandler' object has no attribute 'export_table_to_point_in_time'
I have a function that exports dynamo data using export_table_to_point_in_time from boto3 in version 1.33.13
client = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    response = client.export_table_to_point_in_time(
    TableArn = self.table_arn,
    ExportTime = self.date_start,
    S3Bucket = self.bucket,
    S3Prefix = self.prefix,
    ExportFormat = self.export_format,
    **kwargs
)

however, when unit testing this function, an AttributeError error appears: 'DynamoHandler' object has no attribute 'export_table_to_point_in_time'
I already tried to create a table in Dynamo, I already tried to mock a Dynamo table but nothing worked

You don't show your full code but I guess you're using moto? If so, that feature is not supported:
https://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/services/dynamodb.html
